# GTM - is there a way to render ads asynchronously after enableSyncRendering() and enableServices() were executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-tag-manager

A site that I have limited access to, but can run any code on this page after DOM is ready, has synchronous rendering enabled for GTM.

It explicitly executes `enableSyncRendering()` and also loads the gtm.js itself synchronously (as it is required for enableSyncRendering() to have any effect, according to GTM documentation).

I need to render an ad in this environment asynchronously, after DOM is ready. Is it possible to revert to asynchronous mode? Executing `googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();` does not do anything, and does not affect on subsequent code executions.

---

I prepare a test page that has the same GTM initialization as the website has, and execute commands to render an ad from console after DOM is ready.

The line: `googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();` appears statically on the page before `enableServices();`

If I comment out the line an ad is rendered. If I return the line it does not.

The code that I execute:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
   googletag.defineSlot('/xxxx/xxx/xx/xxxx/xxxxx', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxx-0').addService(googletag.pubads()); 
   googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxx-0'); 
   console.log("The ad should have been loaded about... now."); 
});
```

Comment: This is about GPT, not GTM, right ?

Comment: Eike Pierstorff, it's about Google Tag Manager, that is used to display GPT.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the question, you seem to use GPT and GTM interchangeably. As I understand it, implementing DFP/GPT via GTM is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Google do not recommend implementing DFP/GPT via Google Tag Manager (GTM).

I had this response from Google Publisher Support:

> ...we don’t 
>   recommend using GTM with DFP Tags. At present, we don't have any Help Center 
>   article regarding this apart from: 
>   https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2787990?hl=en&ref_topic=2772416
>
> We are planning to include the option to use GTM for publisher website in near 
>   future but at the moment we don't have any ETA. However you can keep an eye on 
>   this [Help 
>   Center article](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/4620708?hl=en&ref_topic=6003219&utm_source=google&utm_medium=onesheeter-internal&utm_term=adv-training&utm_campaign=onesheeter-internal)
>   to keep yourself updated on new releases or for any updates related to 
>   DFP.